# How to pull all the product id, skus, product names, description in magento using only mysql?

Tags: mysql, magento

How i will pull all the prduct ir, skus , product name (titles) and desxription using mysql from Magento database? I used following query and got all the attributes except product names.

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku, eav.value AS 'description'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_text eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'description'
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please write the full code here? Which table contains product name?

Comment: @user3580780. I don't think the way you are doing it is reliable. There are many attributes in the `eav_attribute` table with the same code for different entities (`description` & `name` are for categories and products). If you do it like this you might get the wrong join condition and you will get no results.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The title can be different from one store view to an other. Same goes for the description. Also, some store views can use the default values set in the backend.

Here is a full query on how to get the data you need (sku, name, description) for all the products for a specific store view (id 1).

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`, 
    IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`,
    IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description`

FROM 
   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` 
               ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` 
               ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` 
               ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` 
               ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)
```

If you want it for an other store view, just replace the value `1` with your desired id at the following lines

```
(`at_name`.`store_id` = 1)
```

and

```
(`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)
```

I don't know why you need this in an sql format. This is a strange and a big error source. You can easily get it through code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'description'));
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $name = $item->getName();
    $description = $item->getDescription(); 
    //do something with $sku, $name & $description
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I know mysql, so trying to find a way to generate sku, title and description using mysql.

Comment: @user3580780. Well...the query above should do the trick. I tested it on the sample database from Magento and it seams to work.

Comment: @user3580780. It it worked, please accept the answer. Don't leave loose ends.

Comment: how do i accept the answer here? is there any kind'f yes / no button so that it shows i accepted it?

Comment: @user3580780 Under the vote count of any answer there should be a checkmark. Click it. Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour in the `Ask questions, get answers, no distractions` section

Comment: Oh got it. accepted it. I also wanted to find product sku and also UNSPSC code for that SKU. Have any idea how do I do that?

Comment: what is UNSPSC code? If that's an attribute of your product then do the same as for name and description. 2 extra joins

Comment: So I have got unspsc code and sku for product. Do you know how to use group by here?SELECT eav.value AS 'unspsc', e.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'unspsccode' - I want to know how many skus in each unspsc?

Comment: Such a magnificent query. Teach me, Master, how did you acquire such knowledge.

Comment: @MJoraid I did a lot of mistakes and had to fix them myself.

Comment: @Marius This query is SO great! I'm running Magento 2.3.6 and got an error running this query because there is no `entity_id` column in those tables. I changed that column name to `row_id` in your query, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

Here is another query to show `entity_id, product_name, sku`

```
SELECT
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.`value` AS product_name,
    catalog_product_entity.sku
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_varchar
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
WHERE
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_type_id = (
        SELECT
            entity_type_id
        FROM
            eav_entity_type
        WHERE
            entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
    )
AND attribute_id = (
    SELECT
        attribute_id
    FROM
        eav_attribute
    WHERE
        attribute_code = 'name'
    AND entity_type_id = (
        SELECT
            entity_type_id
        FROM
            eav_entity_type
        WHERE
            entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
    )
)
```

Comment: this does not work if you have a value set for name on global values and a different one on a specific store view. Your query does not take into account the store view. I think it retrieves all the values for all available store views.

Answer (score 3):

For fetching the product name please try

```
$sql = "SELECT `value`
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))";

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

This query contain Product `name`, `image`, `price`, `quantity`, `description`

```
SET @etype = (SELECT 
                    entity_type_id
                FROM
                    eav_entity_type
                WHERE
                    entity_type_code = 'catalog_product');
```

Product `name` attribute ID

```
SET @name  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'name'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
```

Product `image` attribute ID

```
SET @image  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'image'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
```

Product small image attribute ID

```
SET @smallimage = (SELECT 
        attribute_id
        FROM 
           eav_attribute
        WHERE 
           attribute_code = 'small_image'
               AND entity_type_id = @etype);
```

Product `price` attribute ID

```
SET @price  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'price'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
```

Product `description` attribute ID

```
SET @description  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'description'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
```

-- Admin store ID
-- SET @store = 0;

```
SELECT 
    e.entity_id AS 'id',
    e.sku,
    v1.value AS 'name',
    v2.value AS 'image',
    s2.value AS 'small_image',
    si.qty AS 'stock qty',
    d1.value AS 'price',
    s1.value AS 'description'
FROM
    catalog_product_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    cataloginventory_stock_item si ON e.entity_id = si.product_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
        AND v1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND v1.attribute_id = @name
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
        AND v2.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND v2.attribute_id = @image 
        LEFT JOIN        
    catalog_product_entity_varchar s2 ON e.`entity_id` = s2.entity_id
    AND s2.store_id IN (0,1,2)
    AND s2.`attribute_id` = @smallimage
    LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal d1 ON e.entity_id = d1.entity_id
        AND d1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
        AND d1.attribute_id = @price
        LEFT JOIN
        catalog_product_entity_text s1 ON e.entity_id = s1.entity_id
       AND s1.store_id IN (0,1,2)
       AND s1.attribute_id = @description ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simple way.

```
select 
sku.entity_id, sku.sku, #get sku and entity
productName.value, #get name
description.value #get description
from 
catalog_product_entity as sku,
catalog_product_entity_varchar as productName,
catalog_product_entity_text as description
where
productName.attribute_id = 73 
and
sku.entity_id = productName.entity_id
and
description.attribute_id = 75
and
sku.entity_id = description.entity_id;
```

Comment: It is good practice to explain what your code does when writing an answer, not just posting the code.