# How to use group by in this cquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how many `sku`s are in each `unspsc`. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT eav.value AS 'unspsc', e.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'unspsccode'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull all the product id, skus, product names, description in magento using only mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337745/how-to-pull-all-the-product-id-skus-product-names-description-in-magento-usin)

Comment: rather unclear, this query as it is does not require a group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT eav.value AS 'unspsc',COUNT( e.sku)
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'unspsccode'
GROUP BY eav.value
```