# How to get all the product id, created date, name, category, price, price_unit, pic_url, description and product_url in magento using only mysql?

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to create a view of all the products with following information from Magento using mysql query. I cannot use the Magento code for it, I have permission only to create the table view.

```
product id, 
created date, 
name,
category,
price,
price_unit,
pic_url,
description,
product_url
```

Comment: I want a query similar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337745/how-to-pull-all-the-product-id-skus-product-names-description-in-magento-usin

Comment: main issue is to get product url and image url. for example, /media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/p/wpd005t.jpg in this image path there is a random folder name (9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95) and its not stored in the database. I want to get the product url (/women/pants-denim/dumbo-boyfriend-jean.html) and the image url.