# Build an sql query for all enabled products in magento database

Tags: sql, magento

I am new to magento and I want to fetch enabled products from the database.The fields I require are:
Name of the product,PRICE ,SKU and Quantity.

I don't have much idea regarding the magento table structure. Is it possible from the admin panel or if someone has a sql query it would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Backend:**

You can Export all enabled Products from admin. You can export this from Top Navigation `System` >> `Configuration` >> `Import/Export` >> `Dataflow - Profiles`.

In `Dataflow - Profiles`, you will see `Export Product Stocks` Profile. you can set Required Fields in `Field Mapping` to export Products with required attribute.

**Using Code:**

You can create stand alone script in your magento installation root directory and add the below code:

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('qty');

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($productCollection);


foreach($productCollection as $_product) {

    $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

    echo $_product->getName() .'<br />';
    echo $_product->getSku() .'<br />';
    echo $_product->getPrice() .'<br />';   
    echo $qty .'<br />';
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I didn't try the backend one but script was perfect. Is it possible to get a raw sql query for this, thanks.

Comment: `getSelect` function return the raw sql using collection object

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 1
```

Source-
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83030/how-to-list-all-disabled-products-with-sql

Also see this post->
[How to pull all the product id, skus, product names, description in magento using only mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337745/how-to-pull-all-the-product-id-skus-product-names-description-in-magento-usin)