# Retrieve Product Details in Magento with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, magento

I am running an analysis for a Magento store on Tableau, which is connected to the DB.
I'm trying to get Product Details in the same Table (Product ID, SKU, Cost, Price and Special Price) through different SQL queries including left joins on the Catalog Product EAV, but still can't get it right.

What would be the SQL query to get those attributes together ? (Not bundled products, just simple products)

I didn't post my queries here because I think the logic might influence any comments.
I know this is a tough one, but thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar kind of report in another php framework known as laravel. The query is bit different since it belongs to laravel however you will get the concept. My requirements didn't have special price so that you won't find here. I will try to edit the answer by tomorrow and give you a proper query:

```
$result=DB::table('catalog_product_flat_1 as t1')
            ->join('sales_flat_order_item as t2', 't1.entity_id', '=', 't2.product_id')
            ->join('eav_attribute_set as t3','t1.attribute_set_id','=','t3.attribute_set_id')
            ->join('cataloginventory_stock_status as t4','t1.entity_id','=','t4.product_id')
            ->select
            (   't1.entity_id','t1.sku','t1.name','t1.url_path','t1.created_at',
                't1.product_type','t3.attribute_set_name','t1.price','t4.stock_status',
                DB::raw('sum(t2.qty_ordered) as sum')
            )
```

You can also refer to one of my previous questions:
[Build an sql query for all enabled products in magento database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196742/build-an-sql-query-for-all-enabled-products-in-magento-database)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following query which works great for me:

```
Select *
From catalog_product_entity, catalog_product_index_price, core_website, customer_group
Where catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_index_price.entity_id
and  catalog_product_index_price.website_id = core_website.website_id 
and  catalog_product_index_price.customer_group_id = customer_group.customer_group_id
/* HEIDER: Enable here if you need to filter Store -- and  core_website.code = 'us' */
/* HEIDER: Enable here if you need to filter Customer Group -- and  customer_group.customer_group_code = 'General' */
Order by sku;
```

I hope this helps,

H